# Can "quam" be used as a mere intensifier to a superlative?

Tags: syntax, adjective, conjunction, superlatives

In a [question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/does-plurimi-imply-vast-majority-in-augustines-enchiridion) about Augustine, this quotation is given:

> Frustra itaque nonnulli, immo **quam plurimi**, aeternam damnatorum poenam et cruciatus sine intermissione perpetuos humano miserantur affectu, atque ita futurum esse non credunt
>   — Augustine, [*Enchiridion*, §112](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/enchiridion/index.htm),
>
> <sup>It is quite in vain, then, that some—**indeed very many**—yield to merely human feelings and deplore the notion of the eternal punishment of the damned and their interminable and perpetual misery. They do not believe that such things will be. ([translation source](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/augustine/enchiridion.chapter29.html))</sup>

This use of *quam* as a mere intensifier ("very") of a superlative surprised me. Perhaps I have seen it before, but I do not recall doing so. Is this normal in (classical) Latin?

To be clear, I am not inquiring about *quam* + superlative as used in e.g. "as many as possible" or "as many as I could find", both of which are common enough, nor about using it as an intensifier with a positive (which is possible though probably uncommon).

I could not find a description of this use in [Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=quam&filter=CUTF8).

Comment: Ahah, the answer you seek appears to be at the very bottom of your link.

Comment: @Anonym: Well, that isn't with superlatives?

Answer (score 4):

I think I have three examples, one modern and two medieval: they were found with ***o quam* + the specific superlatives** in the search box.

[De Maximiliani Romanorum](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IcNTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP63&lpg=PP63&dq=o%20quam%20pulcherrima&source=bl&ots=Xpknh4XqHe&sig=w6dX2lc_yZV1vDzia78U02Om35o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1sLfmrpveAhUlK8AKHYHfAY8Q6AEwEHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=o%20quam%20pulcherrima&f=false). Imperatoris ... laudibus ... epistola;  By Paul von Oberstein (quire Giij; no page numbers)

> *o quam pulcherrima laus, quam ingens gloria Bohoemici nominis*
>   O, how very beautiful the praise, how vast the glory of the Bohemian Name.

a medieval/early modern [devotional work](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SgRTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=o%20quam%20pulcherrima&source=bl&ots=qRyh_kG1Tz&sig=FYFzS5CedNnePzC9CvBzfLHisD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzr53RrZveAhXMK8AKHTcuDQs4ChDoATAJegQIARAB#v=onepage&q=o%20quam%20pulcherrima&f=false):

> *Ex his adverte o anima devota, quam pulcherrima, quam gloriosissima sit Maria mater domini Jesu*.
>   From these notice, o devoted soul, how very beautiful, how very glorious is Mary mother of the Lord Jesus

Notizia Fioretina (1720); forms of address 1002 -1014.

> *'Quam gloriosissimus Avunculus noster Otho Major,*
>   How most glorious a Patron our Otto Major,

Comment: Ah! Your answer has quotations where *quam* is translated as "how", which I would call an interrogative. The "very" in those translations comes from the superlatives themselves. Even so, I think you've put us on the right track: I think *quam* in 'my' Augustinian quotation is indeed the same quam, to be translated as "indeed, how very many". That makes sense; I wonder why I didn't see it. Perhaps it was the slightly liberal translation "indeed very many" that somehow led me astray.

Comment: @Cerberus But is this *quam* 'how' really an interrogative? No question has been asked and no answer is expected.

Comment: @Anonym: Well, I think that's what it and the word "how" are normally called, but I would say it hovers in between interrogative adverb and conjunction (as many words do). In either case, it introduces an (elliptical) clause. So in the *o, quam pulcherrima laus* example, the original construction from which this elliptical use is derived is probably something like *o, [mirabile est] quam pulcherrima laus [sit/est]*, or similar. So in Augustine, it is probably best thought of as *[mirabile est] quam plurimi*, "it is amazing how very many", which can then be liberally translated as "very many".